# adding responsive points to an svg image - onclick

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a human body SVG image, I want to add a point on the exact place I click on this Image, I added the points successfully **but the problem that these points are not responsive**

when the Image size changes or the page size changes for any reason the points position changes, how can I solve this problem?

I want to make the **points placed in the same exact place**, that I clicked, **when the image size or window size changes**, so I can save the case of the image as it is with the new points added and display it in other places of my website

Here is my code

**HTML code:**

```
<img src="body.svg" usemap="#bodymap" class="human-body">
```

**CSS code:**

```
.human-body{
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
}
```

**Jquery code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  const size = 4;
  $("img").on("click", function(event) {
      var x = event.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
      var y = event.pageY - this.offsetTop;
      $(this).parent().append(`<div style="width: ${size}px; height: ${size}px; background: red; position: absolute; top: ${y + size}px; left: ${x + size}px; border-radius: ${size}px"/>`); 
  });
});
```

Here is also a preview for the Image that I use, *known that I use SVG version of that image, not this PNG version, the PNG version here just for preview*

[image]

Comment: can I use percentage for example?